# Graph $G$ has $134$ edges and $67$ vertices. All vertices of $G$ except $p$ and $q$ have a degree of $4$. Find all values for $\deg(p)$ and $\deg(q)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, solution-verification

**Problem:**

Graph $G$ has $134$ edges and $67$ vertices. All vertices of $G$ except $p$ and $q$ have a degree of $4$. Find all possible values for $\deg(p)$ and $\deg(q)$ considering $\deg(p)<\deg(q)$ and edge $pq$ is a bridge.

**Attempt:**

$67-2=65$ vertices have a degree of $4$.

The sum of all degrees must equal twice the number of edges, thus

$$65\cdot 4 +1 \cdot \deg(p)+1 \cdot \deg(q)=2\cdot 134$$

from which

$$\deg(p)+\deg(q)=8$$

Considering $\deg(p)<\deg(q)$, we get that

$1$. $\deg(p)=3$ and $\deg(q)=5$

$2$. $\deg(p)=2$ and $\deg(q)=6$

$3$. $\deg(p)=1$ and $\deg(q)=7$

Is this correct?

Comment: You have not used the last condition yet.

Comment: I know, but how am I supposed to use it?

Comment: Start from the definition of a bridge, and see where that gets you. You may have already seen the result that a $4$-regular graph cannot have bridges; this is related.

Comment: For all three cases, if $pq$ is removed then the number of connected  components increases. If $p$ has a degree of zero it is still connected..

Comment: What are the degrees in each of the components?

Comment: Degrees of $p$ and $q$ or the sum of all degrees in each component or..? If $p$ is by itself it should be 2, 1 and 0 right?

Comment: @dukt Not quite right. If $H$ and $F$ are components of graph $G-pq$ and $p\in V(H)$, then $\operatorname{deg}_H(p)$ is an even number (why?). So $\operatorname{deg}_H(p)=0$ or $=2$.

Comment: @kabenyuk So the 2nd option $\deg(p)=2$ and $\deg(q)=6$ is false? Because when we remove $pq$ it would imply that $p$ is a leaf vertex (degree of one), so our bridge would in a sense be "longer" than just $pq$?

Comment: Yes, the case $\operatorname{deg}_G(p)=2$ (or $\operatorname{deg}_H(p)=1$) is impossible. It follows from the handshake lemma that the number of vertices of odd degree is even. But in the graph $H$ all vertices except $p$ have degree 4.
Well, construct two graphs when $\operatorname{deg}_G(p)=1$ and $\operatorname{deg}_G(p)=3$